# Copy Paste in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I have a slight problem. Suppose I have two lyx documents `doc. 1` and `doc. 2`. I want to copy from `doc. 2` to `doc. 1` and then apply text style used in `doc. 1`. When I use the usual `ctrl + V`, `ctrl + C`, I get the style of `doc. 2` in `doc. 1` and have not managed to apply styles in `doc. 1` to the copied content. I also tried to use paste special options but this did not help. More precisely my question is whether I can somehow apply font default do the copied content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that, `doc 1.` and `doc. 2` need to have the same relevant style rules being applied to them - which come from the document classes and the Premables of each document (and manually-written LaTeX (outside of the Premables), which will affect after rendering a PDF or whatever that you'd render).

Make sure that there's nothing that causing any difference in the styles.

For me, such copying and pasting works in LyX.